# Use of sophisticated words (to muddy the waters?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms, connotation, errors

**EXAMPLE:**

In probability theory and statistics, variance is the expectation of the squared deviation of a random variable from its mean. Generally, it measures how far a set of (random) numbers are spread out from their average value.

Poker players and journalists use the word "variance", where people would normally use the word "luck" or "bad-luck". They use it inappropriately or with syntax errors (e.g. "it is due to variance", "you have to beat variance" etc.).

My take is, that this is due to players liking to downplay the effect of luck on poker and present it more as a skill based game. Luck has bad connotations with "gambling". Variance sounds more "scientific" and less "gambling".

My question is, can you give me other examples of sophisticated words being used inappropriately or where a more common word would get one's point across better? Why are people doing this?

Comment: In game theory, *variance* is technically more appropriate terminology than *luck*. I don't believe the premise that it is deliberately used to downplay the effect of luck, or to make poker players seem more skilled, so I find the question unanswerable.

Comment: examples?  ther are many many easily found with a web search.  Why ... many opinions as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case of euphemism (Greek "good speaking").  Euphemisms are used to camouflage something unpleasant, offensive or embarrassing.  The military does it a lot (viz. "collateral damage" for the unintended injuring or killing of civilians; "resettlement" for deportation; "liquidate" for kill, and so forth).

(https://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphemism)

But there are also non-political uses of euphemisms, i.e. "carnal knowledge" for "sex," "comfort woman" for "prostitute," "departed" for "dead," and so forth.